# set max width and height in percentages of screen size for lightbox image

Tags: lightbox2

I am using Lightbox v2.51 by Lokesh Dhakar. Is there a way to set max height and width value according to users screen resolution? I want to have the images fill most of the screen area. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is possible, of you read the manual you will find it.